# JavaFX problems with touch input

Tags: java, javafx, touch, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I am trying to run a program written in JavaFX on Raspbian connected to a DELL P2714T monitor, and it fails to get touch input. 
I keep getting the following error in the printout everytime I touch the screen:

"com.sun.glass.ui.lens.LensApplication nativeEventLoop
SEVERE: 4194 udevInput.c:1596 lens_input_pointerEvents_handleSync: malformed multi touch event - ignoring"

The touch screen is working otherwise, I can click and open some applications.

The input event devices look like this:

pi@raspberrypi /dev/input $ ls -la event*

crw-r--r-- 1 root root  13, 64 Aug 19 12:07 event0

crw-rw---T 1 root input 13, 65 Aug 19 11:45 event1

crw-rw---T 1 root input 13, 66 Aug 19 11:45 event2

crw-rw---T 1 root input 13, 67 Aug 19 11:45 event3

and when I use "cat event0" , I can see a lot of stuff appearing in the output everytime I touch the screen.

Any thoughts on this ?

Comment: I am seeing this same exact issue, curious if you ever made any progress on it?

Comment: @RexRemus: No, I didn't manage to get it to work. I think it has something to do with the drivers for touch input.

Comment: I was going to try a different distro and move to python, but evtest is showing possibly good/useful information off the event bus for my touch device. I was able to write some code to parse the raw output coming off /dev/input/eventN and i'm going to try and polish that up a bit and use it for my app - my use case is very simple though, otherwise I'm not sure I would pursue this route.

Comment: Same thing here. I use RPI2 with JavaFX 1.8.0-b132 and a HANNS-G touchmonitor. Good to know, that I am not alone. I will post something, if I fixed it on my side.